# How do you ssh into a Google Compute Engine Disk?

Tags: ssh, storage, google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I have linked a Persistent Volume to my Kubernetes Neo4j Replication Controller to store the DB data. Now I would like to access this Drive to copy its content.
The gcould api offers:
`gcloud compute ssh instance-name`
but its not an instance its a drive, so how can you connect to it ?

Comment: does your filesystem have integrated SSH server?

Comment: Hi! how about mount this volumen into a instance, then connect it via gcloud compute ssh?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov the honest answer is I don't know, I am letting Kubernetes do all the heavy lifting here as I am a noob in this atm lol

Comment: @Nico Yes I commented below, I think this is what I will try. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. You should think your disc as a physical disk. If your physical disk is unmounted then you can't access it. If you want to access to Neo4j data then the best way is through your Ne4j instance. 
Also you can mount this persistent disk in another instance and through it access to your data. Check [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk) to do that.

**Update:**

If you have access via ssh to the instance where your disc is mounted (Neo4j instance), then you can transfer your data via scp copy to/from your local computer. Take a look [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/scp.htm).

Comment: Yes I have access to the drive through the docker process, but as my objective is to download its content to my local machine I wasn't sure as to how to do that. From what I understand now I should mound the disk (again) outside the docker process on the Node basically, and then I will be able to ```gcloud compute copy-files ...``` and access to my data is that correct ? (sorry for the noob question...)

Comment: No problem :). Souds good. Also you can make an snapshot of your prod disk and mount this copy. Take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/snapshot)

Comment: I haven't had the time to get back on this, I will update as soon as possible

Comment: I did it :), so in my configuration my disk image was in /dev/disk/by-id/DISK-NAME. So I mounted it on the node /mnt/DISK-NAME and now I can gcloud compute copy-files ;)